# Not able to see created Node in Neo4j/console http://localhost:7474

Tags: neo4j

I am trying Java code below and its work fine as expected but problem is i am not able to see created node in neo4j/database in localhost:7474 console. I have restarted server but still same problem,can anyone please help.And I also doubt that is these node created in system memory?

```
void createDb() throws IOException
{
    graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "target/neo4j-hello-db" );
    registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
    BufferedReader CSVFile = null;
    int i=0;
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    try
    {
     CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/sumit/Total_Keywords(0 - 3300000).csv"));

          String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
    while (dataRow != null){
        i++;
     if(i==200)
         break;
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");

     for(String item:dataArray)
     {
        node = graphDb.createNode();
        node.setProperty( "name", item );
        System.out.println( node.getProperty( "name" ) );
        tx.success();
     }
     dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
    }
    }
    finally
    {
        tx.finish();
        CSVFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still having this issue myself. My instinct is telling me that the Java API somehow always creates a separate database that the console can't access without making some unique configuration changes.   What system are you running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check if the server you are looking at is pointed to correct db.

The location of the file is

> conf/neo4j-server.properties

Check the following line and see if it has the correct path that you are using in your code.

> org.neo4j.server.database.location=target/neo4j-hello-db

Comment: Finally, got the solution Thanks it's working now.It eat up my 2 days hope by seeing this solution other beginners can save their valuable time....One more thing missing by me was gave permission to neo4j user to directory in which database files are located..

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure both are pointing to the same directory? I see in your code above that your pointing to `target/neo4j-hello-db`, which by default the neo4j console directory is `../data`. Either change the server directory location(done in `neo4j-server.properties`) or change the directory that your embedded database points to.

Comment: org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/

Comment: Yes now i am sure, I have cross check both is pointing to same path I mean in                neo4j-server.properties                    org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=target/neo4j-hello-db           and in my code. I have also tried from default directory provided by neo4j. But still the created node is not reflected in console.

Comment: You're dealing with a relative problem. When you do `org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=target/neo4j-hello-db`, it's going to still create one relative to your neo4j installation. Try something like `/data/db/` in both your code and `org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri`

Comment: When i try /data/db/ it give me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete /data/db/user_recommendations_profile_test.ns. But when i tried db/data/ it executed with no trouble without any exception...and i always make sure that db_path is same as define in neo4j-server.properties, And also i restarted server but still node is reflected in database..