# Created Nodes doesnt displaying in console in neo4j

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

i tried the sample application provided in the link..https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0-M05/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java

i used neo4j 1.8.3 and java 1.6

in neo4j.server.properties the db location i set like

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=C:\\Program Files\\neo4j-community-1.8.3\\data\\smple
```

and in the embeddedNeo4j programme

```
private static final String DB_PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\neo4j-community-1.8.3\\data\\smple";
```

Iam able to see that nodes created in the Dashboard but iam unable to see in the Data Browser.

Already referred this link
[Not able to see created Node in Neo4j/console http://localhost:7474](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515188/not-able-to-see-created-node-in-neo4j-console-http-localhost7474) but this didnt helped .

Can any one help me?

Comment: Please post the code you wrote to insert data into the db

Comment: @Luanne the same data in the link..https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0-M05/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Webadmin, please go to the Server Info tab- what is the value of store_dir?
Then in the Power console, execute:

```
start n=node(*) return count(n);
```

What does that give you?

Noticed you're using the example from Neo4j 2.0 where you don't have to call tx.finish()

In 1.8.3 you do need to call the finish() method on the transaction else it won't commit. 
See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/1.8.3/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java please and try

Comment: store_dir value is C:\Program Files\neo4j-community-1.8.3\data\smple and count iam getting as 1

Comment: eclipse work space is in D drive and my neo4j server environment is in C drive..any problem with that..?

Comment: Edited my answer- please use the example from 1.8.3 or make sure you call tx.finish()